# Sender information in CalendarApp.CalendarEvent

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a bit baffled! Many of my customers send me GCal invites but the creator shows up as me. I want to extract the actual sender address from the CalendarEvent. See screen shot as an example. Kathryn is the sender but I am listed as the sender.

[Sample screen shot showing different sender vs. creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXwW4.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details about how the events are created, including the code related to the event creation? Why do you think the other person should be the sender?

Comment: The screen grab above was taken from a Microsoft Teams invite that came to me from outside my organization. I did not create the event programatically. Despite this, the creator is me even though the sender is not me.

Comment: This probably means Kathryn is the event organizer despite you being the creator. If I understand you correctly, you are able to retrieve the [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) and you want to know how to retrieve Kathryn address from there?

Comment: Yes - that's correct. To date, I have found no way to do so. For example, Kathryn is not on the guest list.

Comment: Do you know the event id from Calendar API? (Note: that's not the same as in [CalendarEvent.getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getid). Or a better question, how are you currently retrieving the `CalendarEvent`? Can you provide the corresponding code?

Comment: I am iterating over the CalendarEvents that come back from querying my one calendar (Enterprise controlled) via getEvents() with time range passed in. The number of events returned consistently matches what I see in Google Calendar.

Comment: This is fantastic. Everything you wrote below checked out for me and now I can finally see the organizer's email. I was wondering if I could update an event's etag property (in Advanced Calendar API) with the organizer's email and then read it from Calendar API (as a tag object). The goal is to not change any displayed properties but still use the Calendar API logic I had written earlier. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

The main name that is displayed in the UI refers to the organizer of the event, which isn't necessarily the same as the event creator (for example, the event creator might call [Events: move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move) to move the event to another calendar, changing the event's organizer - see [Organizers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#organizers)).

#### Solution:

You can retrieve the event organizer if you use [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) (I don't think that's possible with Apps Script [Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar), since [GuestStatus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/guest-status) doesn't seem to return `OWNER` in all appropriate cases, at least from my experience).

An easy way to use the API in Apps Script is to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (in order to use that, you'll have to [enable the advance service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) first).

Then, using the API you could:

1. Use [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to list the events in your desired calendar according to a time range, as you are already doing with `CalendarApp`.
2. Retrieve your desired event.
3. Access the field [organizer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#organizer) of your event, which contains the organizer's email address as well as other information about this user.

#### Code sample:

```
function getOrganizer() {
  const calendarId = "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID";
  const optionalArgs = {
    "timeMin": "2021-05-17T00:00:00-02:00", // Change accordingly, min end time to filter
    "timeMax": "2021-05-19T00:00:00-02:00" // Change accordingly, max start time to filter
  };
  const events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs)["items"];
  const event = events[0];
  const organizer = event["organizer"];
  console.log(organizer);
  const organizerEmailAddress = organizer["email"];
  console.log(organizerEmailAddress);
}
```